# DDD, How to handle Aggregate roots which share data?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I'm currently working on a Rental Real Estate application (PHP) and I'm trying the get my head around DDD...

At the discovery of the 'Rental Period' bounded context(BC) and 'Billing' BC, I noticed that both BC's have a 'Tenant' aggregate root(AG). But the meaning of a 'Tenant' seems to differ in each BC.

In the 'Rental Period' BC there is a business rule that all tenants should be at least 18 years of age. So the Tenant AG should have a 'TenantId', 'TenantName' and a 'DateOfBirth'.

In the Billing context things like, the 'TenantID' 'TenantName' and 'BillingAddress' are important, but not the tenants age.

None of these two BC's has 100% of all the tenant data.

So my question is, does this imply that there should be a separate BC (TenantManagement), who owns 100% of a tenants data, and that the tenants in the other two BC's will only have a subset of this data, which should be treated as read only?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely: no. There should not be a 'TenanatManagement' BC. The Tenant is a different concept inside the Rental Period BC and inside the Billing BC. In DDD you don't model around data, and there is no need for a central data model. One goal of splitting the domain in subdomains is to avoid having unrelated and maybe contradicting concepts in a single model.

Comment: I see, but this raises new questions like, how to handle a tenants creation?

From a user of the application point of view, I think he would expect to have something like a general Tenant page(UI), where you're able to create of edit a tenant. 

How would this work? They both have to share the identity.

Comment: Well, every BC can create Tenants. Is there a need for integration? Do you want to let Rental Period know that there is a new Tenant in Billing and vice versa? Do you have a requirement or business rule that forces you to correlate the tenants accros the BCs? Or is it possible that the Billing context can simply create Tenants and send bills and the Rental Period can create Tenants and check the age? Ideally every BC is a self-contained system with its own UI and integration is done on UI level.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, in DDD, its totally OK to have data duplication.

Data centralisation is a traditional concept and have been the cause of high coupling for years, among under performance in software.

The goal of having separate BC is to have loose coupling, so its a good practice to have data duplication.

What you need to watch out is how they are updated, by a message listener ? Who is the data owner ? Billing service ? rental management ? both ? an external system ? That's the questions you need to ask yourself and then you just implement listeners on your two BCs.

Comment: Lets say that the RentalPeriod BC is the owner side, then when a Tenants gets created a ApplicationEvent is raised to inform other BC's. Billing is listening to UserCreatedEvent and wants to create a Tenant, but... It doesn't have a all the data required to do so. So it looks like the user of the system needs to provide the additional data needed or something. And what about the identity they share?

Comment: There is multiple ways of doing it, either your ApplicationEvent (which should be more explicit, e.g. TenantRegistered) contains all the information you need (Basically all the fields of a Tenant flattened, so your event is immutable), or you provide a read API to your RentalPeriod BC which allows downstream BCs to query them and the event just contains the ID.

I tend to implement the first option. Then when you update the name or adress of a Tenant, you throw some events such as TenantNameChanged, or TenantContactInformationChanged, and so on